Sequelize findAndCountAll: Pagination and Search Conflicts with Subquery in hasMany Relationship
     Texperts.findAndCountAll({
        subQuery:false,
        where:{
          ...(searchKey && {
            [Op.or]: [
              { '$user.full_name$': { [Op.like]: `%${searchKey}%` } },
              { '$tags1.tag.name$': { [Op.like]: `%${searchKey}%` } },
            ],
          }),
        },
        attributes: {
          exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"],
          include: [
            [
              Sequelize.literal(`(
                SELECT count(*)  FROM texpert_service_bookings AS bookings
                INNER JOIN texpert_services AS services ON services.id = bookings.service_id INNER JOIN texperts as t ON t.id=services.texpert_id AND t.id=Texperts.id
              )`),
              "totalBookings",
            ],
            [
              Sequelize.literal(`
              CASE
                WHEN Texperts.user_id = ${user_id} THEN NULL
                ELSE EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM connections  
                  WHERE (connections.accepted = ${true}) AND (connections.from_userId = ${user_id} AND connections.to_userId = Texperts.user_id) OR (connections.to_userId = ${user_id} AND connections.from_userId = Texperts.user_id)
                )
              END
            `),
              "is_connected",
            ],
          ],
        },
    
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            where: {
              userId:{[Op.not]:user_id}
            },
            attributes: USER_DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES,
          },
          {
            model: TexpertTags,
            as:"tags1",
            subQuery:false,
            attributes: ["tag_id"],
             where: {
                  ...(tag_id && {tag_id }),
                },
                include: [
                  
                  {
                    model: TexpertTagsData,
                    subQuery:false,
                    as:"tag",
                    attributes: ["id", "name"],
                  },
                ],
          },
          {
            model: TexpertTags,
            as:"tags",
            attributes: ["id"],
            include: [
              {
                model: TexpertTagsData,
                attributes: ["id", "name"],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            model: TexpertServices,
            required:true,
            attributes: {
              exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt", "deletedAt"],
            }
          },
        ],
    
        order: [[Sequelize.literal("is_connected"),"DESC"],[Sequelize.literal("totalBookings"), "DESC"]],
        distinct:true,
    
        // Pagination
        ...(page &&
          size && {
            offset: (page - 1) * size,
            limit: size,
          }),
      });

In this TexpertsTags has hasMany relation with Texperts table. and TexpertTagsData table is belongs to TexpertsTags table.
when i try to get data by like query in the parent where condition with subQuery: true, error occured ( unknown column tags1->tab.name), when subQuery: false , searching is working fine but pagination is not working. data is duplicating and data is getting with unexpected counts.
{ '$tags1.tag.name$': { [Op.like]: %${searchKey}% } } when this searching is removed pagination and other search working fine.
{ '$tags1.tag.name$': { [Op.like]: %${searchKey}% } } when removing this search everything works fine.
This query would work perfectly with a raw SQL query, but I need a solution using Sequelize. How can I fix this issue so that both search and pagination work together?
